# Allocator Aware Container and propagate_on_container_swap

Tags: c++, c++11

The `std::allocator_traits` template defines a few constants, like `propagate_on_container_copy/move_assign` to let other containers know whether they should copy the allocator of a second container during a copy or move operation.

We also have `propagate_on_container_swap`, which specifies whether the allocator should be copied during a swap operation.

Is it really necessary for an Allocator Aware container to check for `allocator_traits<A>::propagate_on_container_swap` in `Container::swap()`?  Usually, I implement swap as follows:

```
Container::swap(Container& other)
{
   Container tmp(std::move(other));
   other = std::move(*this);
   *this = std::move(tmp);
}
```

In other words, I simply implement swap in terms of move assignment.  Since the move assignment operation already has to deal with allocator awareness (by checking `propagate_on_container_move_assign`), is it okay to implement `Container::swap()` like this, instead of writing a totally different `swap` function which explicitly checks for `propagate_on_container_swap`?

Comment: What if `propagate_on_container_move_assign` differs from `propagate_on_container_swap`?

Comment: That's a good question... under what circumstances would that even ever be desirable to have different behavior for move vs swap?

Comment: If a container uses a sentinel node, then even move construction/assignment requires a dynamic allocation and may throw, while you can implement easily a `swap()` that doesn't dynamically allocate and doesn't throw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is important to draw a distinction between requirements the standard places on your code vs the requirements it places on types provided by the implementor of the std::lib.

The container requirements specify how the std::containers must behave.  However you are free to write your container however you like.  Unless you input your container into std::code which requires the std::container behavior, you are good to go.  There are just a couple of such places.  For example if you adapt your `Container` with `std::stack`, then you will have to provide standard behavior if you expect the `std::stack` to behave according to the standard.

Getting back to your question, if you desire your `Container` to have the same behavior as one of the std::containers in this regard, then you will have to check and abide by *all* of the `propagate_on` traits, and all of the other allocator requirements.  This is a non-trivial task.  And I am not necessarily recommending it.

The std::containers will not perform a container move construction nor move assignment during `swap`.  They will instead swap their internal representations.  They will decide (at compile-time) based on `propagate_on_container_swap` whether or not they will swap allocators.

If `propagate_on_container_swap` is true, they will swap allocators and internal representations.  Also in this case, `swap` will be `noexcept` in C++1z (we hope that is C++17) and forward.

If `propagate_on_container_swap` is false the allocators shall not be swapped, and need not even be `Swappable`.  However the container internals are still swapped.  In this case, if the two allocators do not compare equal, the behavior is undefined.

If you keep your `Container::swap` as it is, and create a `std::stack` based on your `Container`, the `std::stack::swap` will not have standard behavior.  However, it will have the behavior of your `Container::swap`, and if that is fine with the client of said `std::stack` and whatever allocator they may be using, then no harm done.  `std::stack::swap` will not behave in mysterious ways just because you didn't rigorously follow all of the intricate details for allocators that the std::containers are required to.

Comment: So `swap` will not be `noexcept` if `propagate_on_container_swap` is false? Why is that? If you're not going do anything with the allocators in that case, then why would it affect `noexcept`ness?

Comment: The current draft spec says:  `noexcept(propagate_on_container_swap || is_always_equal)` where `is_always_equal` is a new trait that is true if the allocators always compare equal.  If both of these are false, then you get into UB if the allocators are unequal.  And at that point there is no sense in promising not to throw.  Anything can happen.  If the allocators *are* equal, then `swap` won't throw.  However in this case you can't know that they are equal until run time, and so there is no sense making a compile time promise with `noexcept`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I was looking at n4140 which doesn't list any `noexcept` spec for the various containers, and the general container requirements doesn't say anything about the `is_always_equal` trait either (because it doesn't exist in that draft :)). n4296 matches what you say exactly.

Comment: So, you are saying that in principle your own containers can ignore these allocator semantic policies in their own implementation (and rely on the default semantics of the copy-assignment, move-assingment and swap of the allocator implementation)? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703727/allocator-propagation-policies-in-your-new-modern-c-containers

Comment: Sure, as long as your clients don't expect your containers to follow the std allocator policies.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can implement it using move-ctor and move-assignment of the container.
That's the way `std::swap` does it though, and there is absolutely no reason to re-write it instead of using the standard one.

Those propagate-constants allow omitting useless extra-work, and you are free t ignore the potential for optimization.
Just be aware that you are potentially doing too much work, aka your `swap` is potentially less efficient.