# Allocator propagation policies in your new modern C++ containers

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, allocator, copy-assignment, move-assignment-operator

What is the reason for having these traits in a container (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits)

```
propagate_on_container_copy_assignment  Alloc::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment if present, otherwise std::false_type
propagate_on_container_move_assignment  Alloc::propagate_on_container_move_assignment if present, otherwise std::false_type
propagate_on_container_swap             Alloc::propagate_on_container_swap if present, otherwise std::false_type
```

```
is_always_equal(since C++17)            Alloc::is_always_equal if present, otherwise std::is_empty<Alloc>::type
```

I understand that the container implementation will behave in one way or another in their implementation of assignment and swap. (and that handling of these case is horrible code.)
I also understand that sometimes one might need to leave the move-from container in a state that is `resizeble` or that at least some very last deallocation can be called, so the allocator can't be left invalid. (I personally think that is a weak argument.)

But the question is, **Why can't that information be already part of the normal implementation and semantics of the custom allocator type itself?**

I mean, container copy-assignment can try copy-assign the source allocator, and if that syntactic copy assign doesn't really copy, then, well, it is like saying that your container *doesn't* `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment`.

In the same way instead of using `is_always_equal` one can actually make the allocator assignment do nothing.

(Besides, if `is_always_equal` is true one can make `operator==` for allocators return `std::true_type` to signal that.)

It looks to me that these traits seem to try *override* the semantics that one can give to the custom allocator by normal C++ means.
This seems to play against generic programming and the current C++ philosophy.

The only reason, I can think of this can be useful to fulfill some kind of backward compatibility with "old" containers.

If I were to write a *new* container and/or an *new* non-trivial allocator today, **can I rely on the semantics of the allocator and forget about these traits?**

In my view, as long as the moved-from allocator can "deallocate" a null pointer state (which means mostly to do nothing in this particular case), then it should be fine, and if `resize` throws, that is fine (valid) too, it simply means that the allocator doesn't have access to its heap anymore.

---

**EDIT:** In practical terms,  **Can I write the containers simply this way**? and delegate the complexity to the semantics of the custom allocators?:

```
templata<class Allocator>
struct my_container{
  Allocator alloc_;
  ...
  my_container& operator=(my_container const& other){
    alloc_ = other.alloc_; // if allocator is_always_equal equal this is ok, if allocator shouldn't propagate on copy, Alloc::operator=(Alloc const&) simply shouldn't do anything in the first place
    ... handle copy...
    return *this;
  }
  my_container& operator=(my_container&& other){
    alloc_ = std::move(other.alloc_); // if allocator shouldn't propagate on move then Alloc::operator=(Alloc&&) simply shouldn't do anything.
    ... handle move...
    return *this;
  }
  void swap(my_container& other){
     using std::swap;
     swap(alloc, other.alloc); //again, we assume that this does the correct thing (including not actually swapping anything if that is the desired criteria. (that would be the case equivalent to `propagate_on_container_swap==std::false_type`)
     ... handle swap...
  }
}
```

I think the only true requirement to an allocator is that, a moved-from allocator should be able to do this.

```
my_allocator a2(std::move(a1));
a1.deallocate(nullptr, 0); // should ok, so moved-from container is destructed (without exception)
a1.allocate(n); // well defined behavior, (including possibly throwing bad_alloc).
```

And, if the moved-from container cannot resize because the moved-from-allocator lost access to the heap (e.g. because there is no default alloctor for a particular resource), well, too bad, then the operation would throw (as any resize could throw).

Comment: You have a collection of classes, say MyFoo, ThisFoo, ThatOtherFoo, each implementing sone kind of Foo. The behaviour of *objects* of each class is encoded in the class. The properties of *the class as a whole* is encoded in an associated traits class, a specialisation of the FooTraits template. You see this throughout the standard library.

Comment: "*This seems to play against generic programming and the current C++ philosophy.*" In what way? Traits classes are used throughout C++, and have been since before C++98 came into being.

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes, but traits generally don't tell other classes how elements are copied and what copy or move "really" means. "Propagate on copy" puts a lot of burden on all cases using the allocator because it will have to have all the cases considered. (I have nothing against traits, I have something against traits that at best are redundant with the semantics and at worst contradictory to the semantics that C++ can allow you to specify). I think there must be a historical glitch.

Comment: @alfC: "*"Propagate on copy" puts a lot of burden on all cases using the allocator because it will have to have all the cases considered.*" It only puts a burden on container implementations, which is a subset of code that may need to copy an allocator. And even then, it only applies on copy *assignment*.

Comment: @NicolBolas, true, only to containers classes I meant (which I happen to be implementing). It applies to move and swap as well. Second question, will my container work with near-future expected standard allocators if I ignore these traits? (see code in the last part where I assume normal semantics for allocator, e.g. themselves as pointers(handles)-to-a-heap https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MdSJsCTRkY)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nicol Bolas's answer is very accurate. I would say it like this:

- [An allocator is a handle to a heap.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MdSJsCTRkY) It's a value-semantic type, just like a pointer or an `int` or a `string`. When you copy an allocator, you get a copy of its value. Copies compare equal. This works for allocators just like it works for pointers or `int`s or `string`s.
- *One thing you can do* with an allocator is pass it around to different algorithms and data structures using pure value semantics. The STL doesn't have much in this department, but it does have e.g. [`allocate_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared).
- *Another thing you can do* with an allocator is give it to an STL container. You give the allocator to the container during construction of the container. At certain points during its lifetime, the container will encounter *other allocators*, and it will have to make a choice.

---

```
A<int> originalAlloc = ...;
std::vector<int, A<int>> johnny(originalAlloc);

A<int> strangeAlloc = ...;
std::vector<int, A<int>> pusher(strangeAlloc);

// pssst kid wanna try my allocator? it'll make you feel good
johnny = std::move(pusher);
```

---

At this point, `johnny` has to make a tough decision: "I'm adopting `pusher`'s elements' values as far as my *value* is concerned; should I also adopt his allocator?"

The way `johnny` makes his decision, in C++11-and-later, is to consult `allocator_traits<A<int>>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment` and do what it says: if it says `true` then we'll adopt `strangeAlloc`, and if it says `false` we'll stick to our principles and stick with our original allocator. Sticking with our original allocator does mean we might have to do a bunch of extra work to make copies of all `pusher`'s elements (we can't just pilfer his data pointer, because it points into the heap associated with `strangeAlloc`, not the heap associated with `originalAlloc`).

The point is, deciding to stick with your current allocator or adopt a new one is a decision that makes sense only in the context of a *container*. That's why the traits `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` (POCMA) and POCCA and POCS all have "container" in the name. It's about what happens during *container* assignment, not *allocator* assignment. Allocator assignment follows value semantics, because allocators are value-semantic types. Period.

So, should `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` (POCMA) and POCCA and POCS all have been attributes of the *container* type? Should we have had `std::vector<int>` which promiscuously adopts allocators, and `std::stickyvector<int>` that always sticks with the allocator it was constructed with? Well, probably.

C++17 kind of pretends that we *did* do it that way, by giving typedefs like `std::pmr::vector<int>` that look very similar to `std::stickyvector<int>`; but under the hood `std::pmr::vector<int>` is just a typedef for `std::vector<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int>>` and still figures out what to do by consulting `std::allocator_traits<std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int>>`.

Comment: This is the point I find strange "At this point, johnny has to make a tough decision"..."The way johnny makes his decision, in C++11-and-later, is to consult allocator_traits<A<int>>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment and do what it says". So,in what sense Johnny makes the decision. The decision is already defined by (the traits of) A, according to your own description. Furthermore if the decision is taken by A then it can be part of the normal semantics of A.

Comment: Also, what do you think of the defaults? That propagate traits are false by default. If they were by default true I think I wouldn't even bother asking all this.

Comment: "in what sense Johnny makes the decision" — Johnny is the one who _decides_ to ask `allocator_traits`. Johnny didn't have to do that. Johnny just did that because he wants to be a good "allocator-aware STL container." Johnny's life goal of being an allocator-aware STL container is _completely irrelevant_ to `A`. `A` is going to go on being `A`, regardless of what Johnny does. `A` is not even aware of Johnny's existence. `A` is minding its own business and pursuing *its* life goal of being a good "value-semantic type."

Comment: Do you imply that by deciding not to follow (or ignoring) the recommendation then a container is going to be a bad allocator aware container? Also, IMO, being a good value semantic type means not trying to impose to others what a copy or a move really means. Maybe I am confusing propagation with copy or move. (Propagation is not a word that means much for me in C++ ). Perhaps propagation is a concept that goes beyond a normal definition of semantics.

Comment: I reviewed your slides and the key is in slide 22"Allocators must be 'copy-only' types". You've good reasons for not liking this requirement. This messes up everything because it forces a possible subversion of the language semantics. The only postcondition should have been that`v.clear()` works (a moved-from allocator *must* be able to "delete null"), but not necessarily succeed in `v.push_back(4)`, which, as usual, can throw `bad_alloc`. My take is: moved-from allocator could `bad_alloc` (simply because it doesn't have a memory resource). That would have weaker and better req. for allocators

Answer (score 7):

> I mean, container copy-assignment can try copy-assign the source allocator, and if that syntactic copy assign doesn't really copy, then, well, it is like saying that your container *doesn't* `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment`.

The concept/named requirement "[CopyAssignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable)" means something more than just the ability to assign an lvalue into an object of the same type as that lvalue. It has a semantic meaning as well: the destination object is expected to be equivalent in value to that of the original object. If your type provides a copy assignment operator, the expectation is that this operator copies the object. And pretty much everything in the standard library that allows copy assignment requires this.

If you give the standard library a type that it requires to be CopyAssignable, and it has a copy assignment operator which doesn't abide by the semantic meaning of that concept/named requirement, undefined behavior results.

The allocator has a "value" of some sort. And copying an allocator copies that "value". The question that propagating on copy/move/swap is basically asking this question: is the value of the allocator part of the value of the container? That question only gets raised in the confines of dealing with containers; when dealing with allocators in general, the question is moot. The allocator has a value, and copying it copies that value. But what that means relative to previously allocated storage is an entirely separate question.

Hence the trait.

> If I were to write a *new* container and/or an *new* non-trivial allocator today, **can I rely on the sematics of the allocator and forget about these traits?**
>
> ...
>
> **Can I write the containers simply this way**? and delegate the complexity to the semantics of the custom allocators?:

A container that violates the rules of an [AllocatorAwareContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer) is not an allocator aware container, and you cannot reasonably pass allocators to it that follow the standard library allocator model. Similarly, an allocator that violates the rules of an [Allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) cannot reasonably be given to an AllocatorAwareContainer, since that model requires that the allocator actually be an Allocator. This includes the syntactic and *semantic* rules.

If you do not provide values for the `propagate_on_*` properties, then the default value of `false` will be used. This means that it won't try to propagate your allocator, so you won't run afoul of the need for the allocator to be copy/move-assignable or swappable. However, this also means that your allocator's copy/move/swap behavior will never be used, so it doesn't matter what semantics you give these operations. Also, without propagation, if two allocators were unequal, it means a linear time move/swap.

However, an AllocatorAwareContainer is still not allowed to *ignore* these properties, since by definition, it must implement them in order to assume that role. If an allocator defines a copy assignment operator, but makes its propagate-on-copy false (which is perfectly valid code), you *cannot* invoke the allocator's copy assignment operator when copy-assigning the container.

Basically, the only way to make this work is to live in your own universe where you only use your "containers" with your "allocators" and never try to use any standard library equivalents with your "containers/allocators".

---

> A historical review can also be helpful.

For historical purposes, the `propagate_on_*` features had a winding history to C++11, but it *never* appeared as you suggest.

The earliest paper I can find on this subject is [N2525 (PDF): Allocator-specific Swap and Move Behavior](https://wg21.link/N2525). The principle intent of this mechanism is to allow certain classes of stateful iterators to be able to have constant-time move and swap operations.

This was subsumed for a time by a concept-based version, but once that was removed from C++0x, it went back to the traits class [with a new name and a more simplified interface (PDF)](https://wg21.link/N2982) (yes, the interface you're using now is the *simple version*. You're welcome ;) ).

So in all cases, there was an explicit recognition that there needed to be a distinction between the existence of copy/move/swap and the meaning of these operation with respect to a container.

---

> and that handling of these case is horrible code.

But it's not. In C++17, you just use `if constexpr`. In older version, you have to rely on SFINAE, but that just means writing functions like this:

```
template<typename Alloc>
std::enable_if_t<std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment::value> copy_assign_allocator(Alloc &dst, const Alloc &src)
{
  dst = src;
}

template<typename Alloc>
std::enable_if_t<!std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment::value> copy_assign_allocator(Alloc &dst, const Alloc &src) {}
```

Along with versions for move and swap. Then just call that function to do the copy/move/swap or to not do the copy/move/swap, in accord with propagation behavior.

Comment: I think the question is less about what the traits *do*, but about why they must be a class separate from the allocator proper.

Comment: @n.m.: He's asking why they have to be separate from the operations themselves. That is, why you don't just implement non-propagation-by-copy in your copy assignment operator, rather than having to make every container do it. They're not actually separate from the allocator; you can define them as member aliases of the allocator just fine.

Comment: Right but clients still acces them through the trait class.

Comment: @n.m.: But the OP isn't asking why it's a traits class; he's asking why do you need to specify the behavior *at all*, instead of just encoding it in the copy operator. Like he said, "Why can't that information be already part of the normal implementation an semantics of the custom allocator type itself?" And just look at his examples. It's not about where you ask the question; it's about asking the question *at all*.

Comment: uh that's what I mean actually. It's nit about tge physical location of the flags obviously.

Comment: Yes, the allocator has a "value" of some sort. I think the most useful way to see that value is that it is a pointer (to a heap), and that's what I think the designers of all this protocol failed to realize (I am not is not an easy problem!). This pointer can be "normal" in which case copy and move are the same or can be "unique" in which move invalidates the source.  Whether it is "normal" or "unique" (or "shared") is up to the allocator-type sematics.

Comment: Once you see it from this point of view I think all this complexity dissapears because the trait is replaced by the actual semantics of the allocator. A contentious point is what to do when "unique pointer to a heap" in a null state tries to deallocate a "nullptr"  or tries to allocate afterwards (solution: nothing and `bad_alloc` respectively). The problem is that (as usual) the defaults `propagate_on_*` are "wrong" (opposite to the canonical), so I cannot ignore all this complexity.

Comment: `if constexpr` is ugly as any `if` :). BTW, thank you very much for your excellent answer. My conclusion is that, even if I accept the state of things (and not try to live my own universe :) ), I can at least blame it to the bad defaults chosen.

Comment: Finally, it just occurred to me that these "wrong" defaults were chosen to handle (the mountrosity of) polymorphic allocators and to handle the weird semantics of polymorphic objects. Do you think it can possibly be related to that?

Comment: @alfC The trait class intends to expose a unified interface for allocator related features. You can view it as the enforcement of the Single Responsibilit Principle. In your allocator, just provide allocation/deallocation + traditionnal copy/move semantics and set the appropriate values for propagation. Then, let `std::allocator_traits` do the tedious work for you

Comment: @Rerito, I know what traits are. The traits I am talking about are different because they try to change the semantics of a class. It is not enhancing the class, it is trying to override the meaning of very fundamental operations in the class, such as assignment and construction. Also, the problem is that the tedious work doesn't end there (at the `std::allocator_traits`): every container implementation (that want to work with standard allocator) is condemned to handle manually several non-standard semantics for the allocators. (yes, `if constexpr` helps but it is still bad IMO).

Comment: @alfC: Well, the thing is more related to *scoped* allocators (the ability to have containers-of-containers share the actual allocator type to be used) than polymorphic ones. If scoped allocators are to work at all, you *really* can't have someone come along and set the allocator of some inner container to a different value, even if the allocator itself could theoretically be set to a different value.

Comment: @NicolBolas, now that you mention scoped allocator, that's making sense. I have to think more about it but it sounds like this can be handled by a shared-pointer (shared-handle) view of allocators that are shared across subcontainers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although I think there is something like an geoengineering  in these protocols I made my container library support all these features of allocators (I hope I didn't mess up.). In particular to support PMR (and classic allocators), https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi#polymorphic-memory-resources .