# Why does std::vector's swap function have a different noexcept specification than all other container's swap functions?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, swap, noexcept

I noticed that the `std::vector` container's swap function has a different noexcept-specification than all other containers. Specifically, the function is noexcept if the expression
`std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::propagate_on_container_swap || std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::is_always_equal` is true, but other containers require the expression `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::is_always_equal` to be true.

Since the behavior of the swap functions is the same, why is the noexcept-specification different in just the `std::vector` container?

Comment: Howard Hinnant apparently answered your question in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309516/allocator-aware-container-and-propagate-on-container-swap#comment44973265_28310100)!

Comment: The comment explains why the swap function's noexcept-specification was implemented that way, but it does not answer the question "why is the noexcept-specification different just in the `std::vector` container".

Comment: Unfortunately I could only find links to non-public discussion on this topic. Maybe it was just caution when they introduced the conditional `noexcept` specifiers for both swap and move operations. It is much easier to verify that it won't cause implementation problems for vector than for the other containers and vector should also be higher priority. The standard library implementation is allowed to use stricter `noexcept` specification than specified in the standard, so that's just the minimum that all implementations should agree upon.

Comment: @user17732522, you may be right. However, if the effects and the behavior of the swap function is the same in all containers, I think the noexcept-specification should be the same to be consistent and guarantee a stricter minimum specification in all implementations. Does it have sense?

Comment: The history of this topic is certainly interesting. The `noexcept(false)` situation can only arise here when using custom, stateful allocators, since the `std::allocator` template is stateless and therefore always equal. Writing such an allocator is something most C++ programmers will not need to do, but apparently Bloomberg had a major codebase using these. Consequently, Bloomberg developers have provided most of the input I found on allocators, swapping and noexcept. The "Lakos rule" on the use of noexcept in the standard library is named after one of them.

Comment: After reading this, it would not surprise me if they were simply using those allocators primarily or exclusively with vectors, and therefore were most interested in making this particular change to the standard.

Comment: The post says "other containers require *only*". This is highly misleading, because it sounds like the "others" have a less strict requirement. But this is the opposite! "Others" require `IAE` (which is strict), but `vector` requires `POCS || IAE`, which is a much looser requirement.